# Text handling and grouping

Tags: javascript

The main idea is that I have a string, with no defined length (dynamic), and I need to group it into multiple columns (like in the image example, ignore the image part)[image].

So, as you can see it has to be precise. The main idea that I have is to split the string intro an array of words, append each word into a container and check if the text container fits into the parent container (that is fixed). Although this idea might work, it seems like an overkill, so, does anyone have a better idea on how to handle this? I cannot use the css property that makes this, it has to be done strictly from js, because I have to further group that text with images in columns.

Just to be clear, I don't have only three columns, this is also dynamic, I can have from 1 to 4 columns.

Comment: Having text with the images is not an issue for the css property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway,

I didn't get the answer I was hoping for, and I implemented it my way, by splitting the text into an array of words and checking for the container dimensions after appending each one. It works!

I still kept the question because maybe someone might need something similar to this.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know about CSS3 multicolumn layout?
See examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts).

Answer (score -1):

Uh... `column-count:3`?

```html
<div style="column-count:3; -webkit-column-count:3; -moz-column-count: 3;">
<p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet capicola landjaeger ribeye beef ribs. Ham landjaeger prosciutto corned beef porchetta, pancetta tongue hamburger meatball picanha pig spare ribs jerky beef ribs venison. Shank sausage swine bacon shoulder pig tenderloin prosciutto rump. Tri-tip ribeye chuck meatball bresaola cow hamburger. Filet mignon cupim jowl tail, ground round corned beef pastrami fatback turducken capicola meatloaf frankfurter jerky spare ribs. Meatball leberkas pork loin pig, tenderloin porchetta pork chop.</p>

<p>Tail cupim sausage flank frankfurter. Jowl ribeye hamburger bresaola sausage, biltong jerky meatball ham hock turkey boudin cupim ball tip tri-tip beef ribs. Shankle tail leberkas, prosciutto meatball kevin alcatra pork tri-tip turkey sausage meatloaf. Short ribs bresaola chicken leberkas pork belly jerky. Bacon shankle turkey drumstick tail.</p>

<p>Chuck flank sirloin tongue short loin meatball, brisket filet mignon. Ham sirloin tongue jowl. Andouille porchetta short ribs pork belly rump shank, pig sirloin pork chop alcatra biltong. Turducken beef ribs jerky fatback shankle pork belly.</p>

<p>Chuck shoulder kevin jowl, pork turducken filet mignon salami picanha. Meatloaf tenderloin short loin swine. Ground round alcatra kielbasa turkey pork. Ground round corned beef tri-tip fatback strip steak short loin cow drumstick. Meatloaf flank strip steak short ribs. T-bone ham hock doner chicken brisket.</p>

<p>Jowl tenderloin meatloaf ham, filet mignon chuck strip steak prosciutto beef ribs shankle frankfurter short ribs shank flank. Strip steak tongue cow hamburger beef ribs porchetta doner pork belly picanha. Hamburger ham hock pork tenderloin pancetta, tri-tip leberkas pig andouille prosciutto meatloaf ground round. Jerky boudin venison chicken. Picanha boudin short loin flank, tail chuck turducken pork belly ball tip drumstick jerky kevin. Brisket ribeye pork, cupim ground round strip steak frankfurter spare ribs kevin biltong ham hock pastrami pork chop t-bone andouille. Sausage pig boudin, shank ball tip chuck porchetta venison doner ham jowl prosciutto chicken tenderloin.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: As I said in the question, I cannot use css. I have to append a number of columns (dynamic, max 4, untill I complete a line of maximum 4 columns, a line that can contain image, video, audio and all kind of content), and after that I need to put a show more button, to append more text (if there is more) in the next line, so I still need to know how much text I appended and I have left. It's much more dynamic than column-count: n. So, I need a logic that's done strictly using javascript.